# Complicated problem for align when a line is too long

Tags: align, vertical-alignment

Now I have an equantion like this:

```
\begin{align}
    & A 
    \\=& 
    \left \{ 
    \begin{aligned}
    & aaa 
         && , bbbb;
    \\ & aaa 
         && , bbb; 
    \\ & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
         &&, bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
    \end{align}
```

[image]

The problem is that the fourth line is too long for the page.

How do I exhibit the following code? Or is there a better way to demonstrate this equation?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to denote the long expression by a specific symbol and explain it somewhere else.

Comment: It mostly depends on the long expressions. Formulas cannot be broken at any point: the typesetter's job is to preserve meaning and readability. Can you show your “real world” problem so better help can be offered?

Answer (score 1):

Now I find a way to cut the long a's into two lines. It looks kind of better.

```
A 
= 
\left \{ 
\begin{aligned}
& aaa 
     && , bbbb;
\\ & aaa 
     && , bbb; 
\\ & 
    \begin{aligned}
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa &
     \\aaaaaaaaaa&
    \end{aligned}
     &&, bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
```

[image]